# Missing resources when building cocos2d-x game with sdkbox's IAP

Tags: android, c++, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, cocos2d-x

I am creating a game using cocos2d-x, it requires IAP so I imported sdkbox's IAP. However, when building it for Android I get the following error:

```
/home/jf/Android/Sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/res/values-v21/appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar
BUILD FAILED
/home/jf/Android/Sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:597: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/jf/Android/Sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:649: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/jf/Android/Sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:694: null returned: 1
```

I tried changing SDK version in my AndroidManifest to 21, 19, 9 and it never worked (Yes I have downloaded them in Android Studio's SDK manager).

I tried creating a whole new project `cocos new "Name" -l cpp -p com.Company.Name`, and doing sdkbox import and compiling without changing anything else.

I don't know what else to try, I'm completely lost.
Thank You!

EDIT: This happens when it
s building the .apk

Comment: Could you provide your `build.gradle` file and`AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: @gerardnimo I'm using proj.android when building. Could that be a problem?